# Random quote from file with PHP

Tags: php

I am wondering how I would be able to have PHP echo a random quote from a text file on a page refresh? I started with something like this:

```
<?php
$strings = array('Quote #1','Quote #2');
echo $strings[array_rand($strings)];?>
```

The issue is there are the actual quotes that would be random and then there is the author that needs to match...

How would I go about doing this? I am new to PHP and have very little skill.

EDIT: 
The difference between this and the other thread is that there needs to be an author that goes along with the quote whenever it's randomized. The quotes and their authors need to match whenever they are displayed!

Comment: How does the quote and author relate?

Comment: There are multiple quotes with multiple different authors. The quotes are in a DIV by themselves and so is the author.

Comment: You have `div`s in a text file? Provide a real example of what you have and what want.